# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Using $this when not in object context when I already included the necessary files

Tags: php, oop, pdo

```php
<?php
$app = [];
$app['config'] = require 'config.php';
require 'core/helpers.php';
require 'core/util.php';
require 'core/Router.php';
require 'core/Request.php';
require 'core/database/Connection.php';     
require 'core/database/QueryBuilder.php';
require 'core/database/Account.php';
require 'models/Campaign.php';
```

This is how I code the Connection.php

```php
<?php

class Connection
{
    public static function make($config)
    {
        try {
          return new PDO(
                $config['connection'].';dbname='.$config['name'],
                $config['username'],
                $config['password'],
                $config['options']
            );
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            die($e->getMessage());
            // exit();
        }
    }
}
```

> and in my `QueryBuilder.php` or `Account.php` file, i refer to it like

```php
class QueryBuilder {
    protected $pdo; 

    public function __construct($pdo){
        $this->pdo = $pdo;
    }
```

this specific query really is the problem here that's why I'm stucked ...

```php
    public static function check_if_the_email_is_currently_registered($pin){
        $sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users WHERE email = :pin";
        $statement = $this->pdo->prepare($sql);     
        $statement->execute();
        $count =  $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM) ; 
        return reset($count); 
    }
```

I get this error

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Using $this when not in object context

Comment: Can't use `$this` in static function. Use `self::` instead or instantiate the object.

Comment: what do you mean instantiate the object ?

Comment: like this one ? ```
$statement = self::pdo->prepare($sql);```

Comment: Instantiate like `new QueryBuilder`. Anyway this seems to be a bad design. `QueryBuilder` class should only build the query, not execute it.

Comment: What do you mean by a bad design @FelippeDuarte. The QueryBuilder and Account class would be the class that creates the queries for me .

Comment: How do I turn `$this->pdo->prepare` to do `self::` ??

Comment: @TheBAST to do that, make your pdo static first before using self, see docs why. and from there you can use `self::pdo`.

Answer (score -1):

`$this` refer to the object instance. when you use static keyword you're referring to the `Class` level not to the `instance` level which is why u get the error. Remember you can call your static function without creating the Object. but you're static function use the `pdo` object which is being created when you create the object QueryBuilder (by using __constructor). hope you figured it out from here.